# jQuery: SimpleModal scrolls to bottom when displayed?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, simplemodal

Using the jQuery plug in http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

I have a simple model div. When it opens, the div scrolls to the bottom of the text. Is this a feature, and if so, how do I get the div to not scroll the contents to the bottom when the SimpleModal shows?

I have tried to force it to scroll to the top.

```
    $(function () {
        $('#agreement-modal-content').modal(
            {
                autoResize: true,
                onShow: function (dialog) {
                    $('#agreement-modal-content').scrollTop();

                }
            }
        );
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>         $('#agreement-modal-content').modal(
>             {
>                 focus: false,    <<<---- Set to false
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue as page did not have doc type defined but I fixed by putting modal as absolute position. Since page might be scrolled and modal could be hidden then, so we need to scroll it to top before calling to show the modal.

Absolute position the modal using css:

```
#simplemodal-container {
position:absolute!important;
top:50px!important;
left:200px!important;
}
```

First scroll top and call to show the modal:

```
// Scroll to top of page so that modal could be visible
$('body').scrollTop(0);

// Show modal now
$('#emailProgress').modal();
```